# Wordpress Bitnami read only .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, web, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I'm trying to update my Permalink by it says " Error: Your .htaccess file is not writable, so updating it automatically was not possible. These are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press Ctrl + A (or ⌘ + A on Mac) to select all. "

Additionally, i tried to configure a sitemap using a plugin it said that i need to update .htaccess

- I tried.htaccess permissions and edit the file, but every time it changes back.
- Tried to configure in apache's settings "AllowOverride All" instead of none but it didn't work.
- I Bitnami's documentation about configuring .htaccess "https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/use-htaccess" and updated the /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/htaccess/wordpress-htaccess.conf as documented.
  Unfortunately, after i restarted apache .htaccess remained the same.

If someone knows how to fix it please let me know, i prefer to make .htaccess writable.

wordpress-htaccess.conf:

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/akismet">
  # Only allow direct access to specific Web-available files.

  # Apache 2.2
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>

        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
  </IfModule>
  # Apache 2.4
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
  </IfModule>

  # Akismet CSS and JS
  <FilesMatch "^(form\.js|akismet\.js|akismet-frontend\.js|akismet\.css)$">
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                Allow from all
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                Require all granted
        </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>

  # Akismet images
  <FilesMatch "^logo-(a|full)-2x\.png$">
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                Allow from all
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                Require all granted
        </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>

</Directory>
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/seo-by-rank-math">
   # START of Rank Math Sitemap Rewrite Rules
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 [L]
   RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)?-?sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 [L]
   # END of Rank Math Sitemap Rewrite Rules
</Directory>
```

Thanks!

.htaccess was remained the same, and not writable. both ways didn't work.